# How to fix the InvalidPipeArgument in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to fix the `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "2019-10-17 09:00:00" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`. this error is came from Safari Browser.

here's the code

***list.component.html***

```
 <div class="date-text" nz-col nzSpan="24">
          {{ dayWeather.date | date: 'EEEE' }}
        </div>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
this.weatherService
        .fiveDayForecast(this.lat, this.lon, unit)
        .subscribe(data => {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.list.length; i = i + 8) {
            const forecastWeather = new Forecast(
              data.city.name,
              data.list[i].weather[0].description,
              data.list[i].main.temp.toFixed(2)+scaleTemp,
              data.list[i].dt_txt,
              data.list[i].weather[0].icon
            );
            this.forecast.push(forecastWeather);
          }

          return this.forecast;
        });
```

Comment: According documentation https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe you need to pass `milliseconds since UTC epoch` parameter to DatePipe, i.e. a number, not a date string.

Comment: Please add  more details as with `2019-10-17 09:00:00` as string this seems to work fine

Comment: @Manish the ```2019-10-17 09:00:00``` is came from openweather api 5 days forecast

Comment: Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zapvy1

Comment: @Manish yes sir its working in chrome but when you test it in safari there's an error

Comment: did you try to convert the space with 'T'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your date as follows before sending it to DatePipe. Safari, won't support this kind of date format: '2014-02-18 15:00:48', **you should change the space to T.**

`'2014-02-18 15:00:48'.replace(/\s/, 'T')`

```
 <div class="date-text" nz-col nzSpan="24">
    {{ validDateFormat(dayWeather.date) | date: 'EEEE' }}
 </div>
```

In your component.ts, create a method to convert the space to T as follows:

```
validDateFormat(dateString) {
  if(dateString) {
    return dateString.replace(/\s/, 'T');
  }

  return null;

}
```

Comment: I have also updated my answer too. please recheck it.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked for me on Safari while date was a string '"2023-04-07 05:43:28"'

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert dayWeather.date  to a Date object : new Date(dayWeather.date).

[stackblitz simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxc114)

From [Angular docs on Date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Format examples
These examples transform a date into various formats,
**assuming that dateObj is a JavaScript Date object** for year: 2015, month: 6, day: 15, hour: 21, minute: 43, second: 11, given in the local time for the en-US locale.

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mm:ss' }}       // output is '43:11'
```

From [MDN on JavaScript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var date1 = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
// Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...

var date2 = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
// Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...
```

Comment: inside the bracket?

Comment: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'